# Is there a quick way to prove that $\sin(x)-x^2$ has exactly $2$ real roots?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, alternative-proof

I found a proof of this fact, but it is not concise as I would like. Would anyone have any advise on how to shorten it? Or an alternative shorter proof? Thank you very much in advance.

$\textbf{Proof}$

Notice that $\sin(x)-x^2$ is $0$ at $0$. Since $(\sin(x)-x^2)''=-\sin(x)-x^2\leq 0$ and is $0$ exactly when $x=0$ it follows that on $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ that $(\sin(x)-x^2)'$ is strictly decreasing. This implies that $(\sin(x)-x^2)'$ has at most one root (its positive at $0$). Since $$\cos(0)-2(0)>0>\cos(1)-2(1)$$ it has a root on $(0,1)$ by Darboux Theorem. Say $y$ is the unique root of $(\sin(x)-x^2)'$.

It follows that $\sin(x)-x^2$ can have most one root on $(-\infty,y)$ and at most one root on $(y,\infty)$. Moreover, by continuity $y$ is not a root. It remains to show that $\sin(x)-x^2$ has a root on $(y,\infty)$. Since $\sin(x)-x^2$ is $0$ at $0$, and on $[0,y)$ it is strictly increasing by continuity it follows that $\sin(y)-y^2>0$. Since $$\sin(2)-(2)^2<0$$
it follows from I.V.T. that $\sin(x)-x^2$ has a root on $(y,2)$. This completes the proof.$\square$

Comment: Perhaps the fact that $\sin x - x^2$ can only have roots in $[0,1]$ can help.

Comment: I tried using that property, but it wasn't really much shorter. I used mostly the same techniques.

Comment: We know that $|\sin x | \leq 1$. So for $x>1$ or $x<-1$, we will have $x^2>1$. This would mean $\sin x \neq x^2$ for $x>1$ or $x<-1$. For $-1<x<0$, we have $\sin x <0$ so $\sin x - x^2 <0$ on this interval.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that the moment after I posted my comment it. I tried to delete it, but I didn't see how. I edited it to reflect my thoughts on the matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already know that $0$ is a root of $\sin x - x^2$. Therefore, you only need to find a range for the other root.

It is easy to see that $\sin x - x^2$ does not have roots for $|x| \geq 1$, so you only need to check for $|x| < 1$.

In this case, we may try simple values of $x$ for which $\sin x$ is known, and see if things work out. For example, $\sin \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac 12$, so we can check if $\frac 12  - \frac{\pi^2}{36} > 0$. Thankfully, it is, since $\pi^2 < 10$. Hence, by IVT there is a root of $\sin x - x^2$  between $\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $1$, since $\sin 1 - 1^2 < 0$. Therefore, there are at least two roots of $\sin x - x^2$.

---

That there  cannot be more follows from Rolle's theorem : if there were three or more distinct roots of $\sin x - x^2$, this would give rise to two distinct roots of $\cos x - 2x$, which would then give rise to a root of $\sin x -2$, which is impossible, as $|\sin x| \leq 1$. Therefore,there are at  most two distinct roots of $\sin x - x^2$. Combining with the previous frame gives the desired result.

This proof avoids the use of the unknown $y$, and instead makes use of the fact that a nice value when plugged into $\sin x  - x^2$ gives a positive value, which can be used to produce a root.

---

Let us call the second root as $l$. So $l$ satisfies $l^2 = \sin l$. The important thing is that $0$ does not satisfy the derivative which is $\cos x - 2x$. In fact, neither does $l$, since $\cos l = 2l$ would imply that $l^4 + 4l^2 = \sin^2 l + \cos^2 l = 1$, and therefore $l$ gives four values, which can be checked to not satisfy $l^2 = \sin l$. Consequently, *up to multiplicity* as well, $\sin x - x^2$ has only two real roots.

Comment: That's a very good idea to use Rolle's Theorem to bound the number of roots. I like it.

Comment: Thank you. the generalized Rolle's theorem, which is an iteration of Rolle's theorem, can be used when the function is easy to differentiate multiple times and the derivatives looks easy to handle, to bound the number of roots that the function can have.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $x=0$ is a solution by inspection.

Now, $x^2 > \sin x$ for all $x<0$ and all $x>1$, so we need only consider the interval $x\in(0,1)$. Since $\sin x = x - \mathcal{O}(x^3)$, we see that $\max(x^2,\sin x)=\sin x$ for small enough $x$, say $x=0.1.$ Because both functions monotonically increase on the interval, there must be exactly one intersection.

Therefore, we have two real roots.

Comment: How do we get the $\mathcal{O}(x^3).$ My analysis text hasn't covered that yet, and I never saw it in undergrad. I know what big O is, just never seen it in this context.

Comment: The Taylor series about $x=0$ of $\sin x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = x - \frac{1}{3!}x^3 + \dots$.

Comment: @zahbaz What about to undelete that [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2659982/505767)?

Comment: @gimusi Are you asking me to cast an undelete vote?

Comment: @zahbaz If you agree that the deletion is not motivated of course! Bye

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, any solution must satisfy $x\in[-1,1]$, since $|sin(x)|\leq1$. $sin(x)=sin(x+2\pi)$, which could mean infinite solutions, but if $x\in[-1,1]$ then $x+2n\pi\notin[-1,1]$, so there are at most two solutions. Zero is a solution, and $sin(x)\leq x^2$ if $sin(x)\leq \cfrac{\pi}{6}$, which you can see from a graph or by looking at their concavity and using the fact that they both pass through the origin, and also $x^2$ is strictly increasing with no asymptote, while $sin(x)$ is bounded, so at some point $x^2\geq sin(x)$, meaning they intersect at some point, since they are both finite in that interval. That means they have at least two solutions, and the fact that it is essentially a quadratic means that there are no more solutions. You can also check this, because $sin(x)$ is negative inside $[-2\pi,0]$, and when it is positive again $x^2$ is too big

Answer (score 0):

Well, consider $f(x) =\sin x-x^2$ and $$f'(x) =\cos x- 2x=1-2\sin^2(x/2)-2x$$ Since $|\sin x|\leq 1$ we should observe that any root of $f(x) $ must lie in $[-1,1]$ and moreover since $x^2\geq 0$ any root must lie in $[0,1]$. Since $0$ is a root of $f(x) $ we consider $x\in(0,1]$ and then $$f'(x) > 1-2(x/2)^2-2x=\frac{6-(x+2)^2}{2}$$ and the rightmost expression is positive for all $x$ with $0<x<\sqrt{6}-2$ and hence $f$ is strictly increasing to the right of $0$ and therefore positive in some interval of type $(0,h)$. And $f(1)=\sin 1 - 1<0$ and hence by intermediate value property $f$ has a root in $(0,1)$. Thus we have established that $f$ has two roots and it can't have more than two because $f''(x) =-\sin x - 2<0$ everywhere. The above approach avoids knowing any specific value of $x\in(0,1)$ for which $f(x) >0$.